# Shifiting a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm not exactly sure what to call this idea. I would like to maintain a balanced binary search tree where, very often, I will add a new highest element to the tree and then delete the smallest element in the tree. Is this at all times a `O(log(n))` operation, or can this specific shift be done in constant time?

Is self-Balancing Binary tree helpful?

Comment: It needs two `O(logN)` operations to be performed. There is no way to do this faster, because BST is not designed to do such things. I am also not sure that it will make your tree balanced.

Comment: (`I'm not exactly sure what to call this idea` - the titles `Shifiting` doesn't ring any of my bells.) I doubt `I would like to maintain a balanced binary search tree` - most of the time, there is data to be held and operations to perform/support: you don't tell which ones.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data stucture you are looking for is called a [binary max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

It is always balanced. The maximum element is always the root, and can be retrieved in O(1) time. All insert and deletes are done in O(logn) time (in the worst case). And there is also a limited size if you implement it as an array. (Can't remember if the minimum value is always dropped on insert).